# how to attach bootstrap theme into cake php project

Tags: cakephp, themes, cakephp-2.0

Here is My Login.ctp file code

```html
  <?php
  echo $this->Flash->render('auth'); 
  echo $this->Form->create('User');
  echo $this->Form->input('username');
  echo $this->Form->input('password');
  //echo $this->Form->input('full_name');
  echo $this->Form->end('Log In');
 ?>
```

[I want such Background(css using Admin Lt Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evGQC.png)

[But I have this view after adding bootstrap CSS File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsSkC.png)

Comment: How about posting the code of your CSS so we can see what you did?

Comment: I am not able to copy here to much heavy css file in code
here is link u can check in this template     https://codeload.github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/zip/v2.3.5

Comment: you dont need to post the entire code. just the code relating to the section you are having trouble with. No code, no help

Comment: Actually i am going to attach this bootstrap theme into my "cakephp" project but i ma unable to do so don't know which code should show you which will help you to help me :(

Comment: We cant help you solve the problem you are having until you figure out what code needs looking at

Comment: Actually there are two many css js and many more map files i am confused in them

Comment: sounds like you need to spend some time identifying the specifics and return after you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the theme login html .....

[image]